# Using localStorage to Remember if User Already Voted

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use `localStorage` to remember if the user has already voted. I have 5 buttons — all with a unique ID to help me keep track of things.

When a user clicks on one of these buttons (e.g., `button-1`), I store the ID of that button with a value. So in `localStorage`, it looks something like this: `key: button-1, value: clicked`.

If the user has already clicked (voted) on that button, it needs to display a message, something like "Thank you for your vote." Otherwise it should keep that button active.

I'm struggling to do this systematically if I have multiple buttons. Do I store a separate key for each button in `localStorage`? Do I append them under one key? I am not sure.

My JSFiddle is here as an example with 3 buttons **http://jsfiddle.net/d8kt69rp**

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="button-1">
  <button value="yes" onclick="recordFeedback(1, this);">Button 1</button>
</div>
<div id="button-2">
  <button value="yes" onclick="recordFeedback(2, this);">Button 2</button>
</div>
<div id="button-3">
  <button value="yes" onclick="recordFeedback(3, this);">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// If user has already voted, just display them a 'thanks' message
if (localStorage.getItem('button-1')) {
    var div = document.getElementById('button-1');
  div.innerHTML = 'Thank for your feedback';
}

// Record user feedback based on the button they clicked
function recordFeedback(id, response) {
    userResponse = response.value;
    var div = document.getElementById('button-' + id);
  if (userResponse === 'yes') {
     div.innerHTML = 'Thanks for your feedback.';
     console.log('button-' + id + ' was clicked.');
     localStorage.setItem('button-' +id, 'clicked');
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You want to retain this if the page reloads? Either way localStorage is only good until they clear their cache or close the tab/window.

Comment: Yes, if a user refreshes the page and they have already voted, it should say "Thank you for your vote" (depending on which button they clicked on). And yes I am aware that if they clear their cache, they will be able to vote again. I am ok with that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/d8kt69rp/2/

HTML (added class to divs):

```
<div class="button-div" id="button-1">
    <button value="yes" onclick="recordFeedback(1, this);">Button 1</button>
</div>
<div class="button-div" id="button-2">
    <button value="yes" onclick="recordFeedback(2, this);">Button 2</button>
</div>
<div class="button-div" id="button-3">
    <button value="yes" onclick="recordFeedback(3, this);">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Wait for DOM to be ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    function() {
        document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.callee, false);
        // Get all the button divs
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button-div');
        var index = 0, length = buttons.length;
        for (; index < length; index++) {
            // For each one check if it has a localStorage value
            if (localStorage.getItem(buttons[index].id) == 'clicked') {
                buttons[index].innerHTML = 'Thank for your feedback';
            }
        }
    }, false
);
```

As for having a key for each or keeping them all together. That's personal preference. Me, I would prefer keeping them together. Feels cleaner although a little more code.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/d8kt69rp/4/

```
function recordFeedback(id, response) {
    userResponse = response.value;
    var div = document.getElementById('button-' + id);
    if (userResponse === 'yes') {
        div.innerHTML = 'Thanks for your feedback.';
        // Get storage and parse it to an object
        var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userResponses'));
        // If storage doesn't exist initialize it
        if (!storage) storage = {};
        storage['button-' + id] = 'clicked';
        // Make it a string and set it
        localStorage.setItem('userResponses', JSON.stringify(storage));
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    function() {
        document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.callee, false);
        var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userResponses'));
        // Don't waste time finding or looping if no votes
        if (storage) {
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button-div');
            var index = 0, length = buttons.length;
            for (; index < length; index++) {
                if (storage[buttons[index].id] == 'clicked') {
                    buttons[index].innerHTML = 'Thank for your feedback';
                }
            }
        }
    }, false
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and going above and beyond to provide 2 solutions with detailed explanation.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. Good luck!